# Can I search within external libraries with VSCode?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I'd like to switch to using VSCode full time, but the one thing keeping me on IntellijIDEA is its ability to search in a project and all libraries added to the project but located somewhere else on the filesystem. In particular, I'd like it to work with Dart. As of yet, I've been unable to find a suitable solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find how to do this in VSCode? Also trying to perform global search on all my code + imported libraries but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workspace symbol list (`Cmd`+`T`) already includes symbols from all of the referenced libaries:

[image: Workspace symbol list]

If you're not seeing this, please file a bug on GitHub.

If you're after a text search rather than symbol search, the only options are to add the folders to your workspace (File -> Add Folder to Workspace) or symlinks (which I wouldn't recommend because they can cause issues with analysis).

Comment: this only works if external library also have sources(in case of compiled laguages). For example, if it contains only `.class`(in case of java) files it doesn't work. Also if external lib contains some configuration files(not type descriptions) they also can't be found